# why sometime my application crash on goBack() webView?

Tags: android, android-webview

why my application crash when i call goBack() method on my WebView?
I post my code

```
     public void workork(final View v){
     //my code
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.chiudi_webview: {

        }
        case R.id.back: {   
            myWebView.goBack(); 
            break;
        }
        case R.id.forward: {
            myWebView.goForward();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked logcat for error messages when it happens? That's a good place to start.

Comment: thanks I will! But what alfo888_ibg says it's right. now it doesn't crash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check if you can go back (the same for goforward()):

```
 if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
    myWebView.goBack();
   }

   if (myWebView.canGoForward()) {
    myWebView.goForward();

   }
```